# laravel homestead, provision not a command

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm following this tutorial:

https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/build-a-cms-with-laravel/lessons/install-and-configure-laravel

However when getting to the step `homestead provision` I get this error:
`[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException
 Command "provision" is not defined.`

This is a problem. If I run `homestead -v`

```
$ homestead -v
Laravel Homestead version 3.0.2

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help  Displays help for a command
  list  Lists commands
  make  Install Homestead into the current project
```

So, provision is not a command. Does anyone have any idea what I need to install to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run this command to reload and provision:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead

Comment: I also had to do this:
`vagrant ssh`,
`serve domain.app /home/vagrant/projects/myproject/public`,

and then

`sudo service nginx restart`.

Just incase anyone runs into the same problems!